# graphql .NET core solution - unable to include related objects

Tags: graphql

I am a newbie to graphql, and use it in a .Net core solution. My solution includes an SQlite-database, that may be accessed via a manager. I use the manager in the resolver functions in my GraphTypes. In the models, I have a class 'Ticket' and a class 'TicketResponse' - one ticket includes a list of ticketResponses.

The problem is that I am unable to include the nested data of an ObjectGraphType. **Here's my code:**

```
namespace SupportCenter.Schema.GraphQLTypes
{
    public class TicketType : ObjectGraphType<Ticket>
    {
        public TicketType(ITicketManager manager)
        {
            Name = "Ticket";
            Field(x => x.Id, type: typeof(IdGraphType)).Description("The id of the ticket");
            Field(x => x.AccountId).Description("THe account the ticket was issued from");
            Field(x => x.Text).Description("The description of the problem");
            Field(x => x.DateOpened).Description("The date the ticket was opened");
            Field<TicketStateEnum>("state", resolve: context => context.Source.State);
            Field<ListGraphType<TicketResponseType>>("ticketresponses",
              resolve: context => manager.GetTicketResponses(context.Source.Id));
        }
    }
}
```

**The error I get is the following:**

> "GraphQL.ExecutionError: No service for type
>   'GraphQL.Types.ObjectGraphType`1[SupportCenter.Schema.GraphQLTypes.TicketType]'
>   has been registered. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No service
>   for type
>   'GraphQL.Types.ObjectGraphType`1[SupportCenter.Schema.GraphQLTypes.TicketType]'
>   has been registered.\n   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)\n   at
>   GraphQL.Types.Schema.b__56_2(Type type)\n   at
>   GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.AddTypeIfNotRegistered(Type type,
>   TypeCollectionContext context)\n   at
>   GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.HandleField(Type parentType, FieldType
>   field, TypeCollectionContext context)\n   at
>   GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.AddType(IGraphType type,
>   TypeCollectionContext context)\n   at
>   GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.HandleField(Type parentType, FieldType
>   field, TypeCollectionContext context)\n   at
>   GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.AddType(IGraphType type,
>   TypeCollectionContext context)\n   at
>   GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.HandleField(Type parentType, FieldType
>   field, TypeCollectionContext context)\n   at
>   GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.AddType(IGraphType type,
>   TypeCollectionContext context)\n   at
>   GraphQL.Types.GraphTypesLookup.Create(IEnumerable`1 types,
>   IEnumerable`1 directives, Func`2 resolveType, IFieldNameConverter
>   fieldNameConverter)\n   at
>   System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)\n--- End of stack
>   trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at
>   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\n   at
>   GraphQL.Types.Schema.get_AllTypes()\n   at
>   GraphQL.Instrumentation.FieldMiddlewareBuilder.ApplyTo(ISchema
>   schema)\n   at GraphQL.DocumentExecuter.ExecuteAsync(ExecutionOptions
>   options)\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---",

I have registered both the TicketType and the TicketResponseType in the services in the startup-file. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my startup-file:

```
public class Startup
    {

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {   
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddSingleton<SupportCenterDbContext>();

            services.AddSingleton<TicketType>();
            services.AddSingleton<TicketInputCreateType>();
            services.AddSingleton<TicketResponseType>();
            services.AddSingleton<TicketStateEnum>();
            services.AddSingleton<ResponseQuery>();
            services.AddSingleton<ITicketManager, TicketManager>();

            services.AddSingleton<SupportCentreQuery>();
            services.AddSingleton<TicketsQuery>();
            services.AddSingleton<TicketsMutation>();

            services.AddSingleton<SupportCentreSchema>();

            services.AddSingleton<IDependencyResolver>(
                c => new FuncDependencyResolver(c.GetRequiredService));

            services.AddSingleton<IDocumentExecuter, DocumentExecuter>();
            services.AddSingleton<IDocumentWriter, DocumentWriter>();

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddSingleton<IGraphQLExecuter<SupportCentreSchema>, DefaultGraphQLExecuter<SupportCentreSchema>>();

            services.AddGraphQL(options =>
                {
                    options.EnableMetrics = true;
                    options.ExposeExceptions = true;
                })
                .AddWebSockets()
                .AddDataLoader();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

                 app.UseDefaultFiles();
                 app.UseStaticFiles();

                 app.UseGraphQL<SupportCentreSchema>("/graphql");

                 app.UseGraphiQLServer(new GraphiQLOptions
                 {
                    GraphiQLPath = "/ui/graphiql",
                    GraphQLEndPoint = "/graphql"
                 });

                 app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should probably show the service registration code too. Also, this probably shouldn't go through service lookup in the first place IMO; the type shouldn't have been missing.

Comment: Ok I'll add the service registration code